# SSIS ODBC error running multiple DFTs connecting to Sybase server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, sap-ase, ssis-2012

I'm getting a strange error in SSIS when connecting to a Sybase ASE server using an ODBC connection. I've got several DFTs connecting to the same server, and when I run the entire package several of them fail mid-way with the error messages below. If I run one DFT at a time, they complete successfully. I've thought about restructuring the package to run them sequentially, but I would lose the benefit of parallel execution, not to mention it would be a lot of work as it's a big package. Hoping someone has seen this before because google hasn't turned up any answers.

> [ODBC Source [14]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. 
>       state: '08S01'. Native Error Code: 30016. [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Bad TDS 
>       response stream received from server. 
>       Unsupported length for TDS_INTN: 111
>
> [ODBC Source [14]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. 
>       state: '08S01'. Native Error Code: 30016. [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Bad TDS 
>       response stream received from server. Unexpected token type received: 109.
>
> [ODBC Source [69]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. 
>       state: '01004'. Native Error Code: 32007. [Sybase][ODBC Driver]String data, 
>       right truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error you are facing is

> Right truncation of string data

According to the following [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/saerrors/errm638.html), the probable cause of this error is:

> Non-space characters were truncated upon the assignment of string data.

**Suggestions**

- You have to increase the size of the parameter/field/variable used

OR

- You can Set `string_rtruncation option` to `Off` so no exception is raised when a truncation is occured.

Based on this [Sybase Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/string-rtruncation-option.html)

> If the truncated characters consist only of spaces, no exception is raised. The setting of On corresponds to ANSI/ISO SQL/2008 behavior. When this option is set to Off, the exception is not raised and the character string is silently truncated.
>
> String truncation may occur in several places. For example, using INSERT, UPDATE, CAST, or assignment to a variable may truncate a string if the declared destination type is too short.

**Similar Problem links**

- [ODBC ERROR "STRING DATA, RIGHT TRUNCATED" WHEN QUERYING DATA IN OPENEDGE DATABASE VIA ORACLE SQL*PLUS](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000037884)